# I am looking for the code in batch that would allow me to Change the error code for ping “request times out” to any text I want

Tags: networking, batch, cmd.exe, ping

I would like to make a ping script that instead of saying "request timed out" it returns something else such as "offline."

I want this to to be output while ping is running not after the command completes.

I am using batch files for cmd

I want this command so when I ping someone it looks more flavorful than request times out.

I am currently trying to find commands that allow me to substitute txt for other txt I have not been successful yet but I do think I am getting closer.

I am experimenting with | find “Request timed out” and if that does work I still don’t know the command that would allow me to replace that txt with what I want.

Comment: I have tried many things in batch none seem to work

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If you ping a server that doesn't exist it is not offline ...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us specifically what you've tried. Saying you tried many things does not help us know what you tried or where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `ping` can be piped to `sed` [for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm):

```
ping example.com | sed "s/Request timed out./Replacement Text/"
```

In the above example, the text *Request timed out.* is replaced with *Replacement Text.*

Comment: Not really a portable solution being sed doesn’t exist in Windows.

Comment: @Appleoddity `sed` doesn't exist by default in Windows, but a compiled version exists for download in the link I provided.

Comment: My point is it’s not portable. It requires installing a third party product to work. This makes it less than desirable. This can easily be done using built-in functionality. My personal preference, depending on the use case, would be to use native tools first. For instance, I wouldn’t want to have to install sed on 1000 computers to run this script, or stage it on a file server and require network connectivity. I’m not saying it’s not a valid or good answer, just that my preference would be native functionality first for something of this simplicity.

Comment: Powershell could also be used, but I'm not aware of an easy solution using built-in Windows commands.

Comment: @davidmneedham whats the link?

Comment: if someone knows the command or a way to change the txt with out 3 party that would be very nice

Comment: @Wings ping returns an errorlevel when it is successful or not. Simply redirect the output of ping to NUL (`>NUL 2>&1`) and `echo` whatever text you want based on a conditional `if` statement then loop and repeat. Nobody is in to writing code for others here. You have to show you at least researched and tried and where you’re confused to get help which is what others have asked you to do.

Comment: Ok I’ll type the code I have rn

Comment: @echo off cls :ping set /p Input=IP/URL: ping %Input% echo press any key to start over pause>nul cls GOTO Ping

Comment: I tried the sed part in bash didn’t work

Comment: And I’ve been trying to get this to work sence Tuesday of last week I’ve watched tutorials they never have what I want I’ve looked on other sites that I can ask questions never any responses ppl who have the code want me to pay $15 for it and I’m not gonna do that.

Comment: @Appleoddity is that enough for you to help me?

Comment: @Wings Listen, you’re welcome to visit us at Superuser with your questions. But there are some basic ground rules to follow. Please read [ask] and EDIT your original question and add all pertinent information you would like to provide, including code samples, error messages, examples of what you are looking for, etc. use proper code formatting so that your question is clear and easy to read. Comments are NOT for back and forth discussion. That is how you get a quality answer. What you are doing now is not.

Comment: I’m sorry I’ve been very frustrated with this topic Andy I don’t mean to come off meaner snappy so I’m sorry about my response is their a way for me to dm you?

Comment: @Appleoddity thank you for not getting annoyed as far as Ik with my responses

Comment: Ok so I may have found something that can help | find /I “Request timed out” but idk the command to replace that txt would it maybe be a / or \ r?

Comment: @Wings edit your question to show what you have tried. It would also be helpful to know what platform you are using and why you want this behavior.

Comment: How does the description of the question look?